# ConfigurationError in Logstash

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

When I run this configuration file:

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/tmp/linuxServerHealthReport.csv"
    start_position => "beginning"
    sincedb_path => "/home/infra/logstash-7.14.1/snowdb/health_check"
  }
  codec => multiline {
    pattern => "\""
    negate => true
    what => previous
  }
}

filter {
  csv {
    columns => ["Report_timestamp","Hostname","OS_Relese","Server_Uptime","Internet_Status","Current_CPU_Utilization","Current_Memory_Utilization","Current_SWAP_Utilization","FS_Utilization","Inode_Utilization","FS_Read_Only_Mode_Status","Disk_Multipath_Status","Besclient_Status","Antivirus_Status","Cron_Service_Status","Nagios_Status","Nagios_Heartbest_Status","Redhat_Cluster_Status"]
    separator => ","
    skip_header => true
  }
  mutate {
    remove_field => ["path", "host"]
  }
  skip_empty_columns => true
  skip_empty_row => true
}

# quote_char => "'"

output {
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

I get this error:

Error:
[2021-09-22T15:57:04,929][ERROR][logstash.agent           ] Failed to execute action {:action=>LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:main, :exception=>"LogStash::ConfigurationError", :message=>"Expected one of [ \t\r\n], "#", "{" at line 7, column 9 (byte 226) after input {\n        file {\n\t\tpath => "/tmp/linuxServerHealthReport.csv"\n                start_position => "beginning"\n                sincedb_path => "/home/imiinfra/logstash-7.14.1/snowdb/health_check"\n                }\n\t\tcodec ", :backtrace=>["/home/imiinfra/logstash-7.14.1/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:32:in `compile_imperative'", "org/logstash/execution/AbstractPipelineExt.java:187:in` initialize'", "org/logstash/execution/JavaBasePipelineExt.java:72:in `initialize'", "/home/imiinfra/logstash-7.14.1/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:47:in` initialize'", "/home/imiinfra/logstash-7.14.1/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline_action/create.rb:52:in `execute'", "/home/imiinfra/logstash-7.14.1/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:391:in` block in converge_state'"]}

Comment: You have an extra curly brackt in line 6, this closes your file input before the codec configuration, remove this and try again.

Comment: I have removed it and tried, but it was failing again, so I added curly bracket at the last of the file section. it is giving me error.

Failed to execute action {:action=>LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:main, :exception=>"LogStash::ConfigurationError", :message=>"Expected one of [ \\t\\r\\n], \"#\", \"{\" at line 24, column 36 (byte 1005) after filter {\n        csv {\n                columns => [\"Report_timestamp\",\"Hostname\",\"OS_Relese\",\"Server_Uptime\",\"Internet_Status\",\"Current_CPU_Utilization\",\"Current_Memory_Utilization\",\"Current_SW'"]}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to work on your formatting, but this is what I have reconstructed from the question. Main issues seem to be parameters of `file`, you put `codec` outside of `file` for some reason. The other issue is `csv` parameters `skip_empty_columns` and `skip_empty_row` which were also outside of `csv`.

So I did a little bit of formatting and fixed those issues and it should work now.

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/tmp/linuxServerHealthReport.csv"
    codec => multiline {
      pattern => "\""
      negate => true
      what => previous
    }
    start_position => "beginning"
    sincedb_path => "/home/infra/logstash-7.14.1/snowdb/health_check"
  }
}

filter {
  csv {
    columns => ["Report_timestamp","Hostname","OS_Relese","Server_Uptime","Internet_Status","Current_CPU_Utilization","Current_Memory_Utilization","Current_SWAP_Utilization","FS_Utilization","Inode_Utilization","FS_Read_Only_Mode_Status","Disk_Multipath_Status","Besclient_Status","Antivirus_Status","Cron_Service_Status","Nagios_Status","Nagios_Heartbest_Status","Redhat_Cluster_Status"]
    separator => ","
    skip_header => true
    skip_empty_columns => true
    skip_empty_row => true
  }
  mutate {
    remove_field => ["path", "host"]
  }
}

output {
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Comment: Code is working, but I'm getting "_csvparsefailure" error:
-----------
{
          "tags" => [
        [0] "_csvparsefailure"
    ],
      "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => 2021-09-23T16:58:06.974Z,
       "message" => "'2021.09.13-10.23.31', 'bfaaprdmon01 ', 'Red Hat Enterprise Linx Server release 7.9 (Maipo) ', '28 days ', 'Disconnected ', '1% ', '7%', '0%', No FSs has threshold abobe 80%\", \"No FSs Inode has threshold above 80%, 'Nll', 'Mltipath_not_configred', 'Stopped', 'Rnning', 'Rnning', 'Stopped', 'Not Configred', 'Stopped'"
}
--------------

Comment: This is a separate question and try to play with it, you can see that there is an issue with CSV so play with the [filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-csv.html). After you give it couple of good tries, come back to stack overflow and ask a new question stating what you tried and also post your CSV so we have something to work off. Good luck!